# How to inspect an external .cpp file?

Tags: resharper

I have in the project a cpp file that is outside the dir tree. Resharper c++ doesn't enable inspection, such as go to definition.

---

Resharper version 2022.1.2

Visual studio 2019 and 2022

It didn't help enabling

options> code editing> c++> inspection> enable on external modules

Also, it's not an external file, it's a cpp that is part of the project.

There's also this

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Options__Tools__External_Sources.html

but the option doesn't appear under tools.

The problem is with resharper; VS inspection (go to definition) works fine.

---

I found the problem, and it's weird. Say I want to add to the project the file:

c:\prj\confstruct\src\debug\mpir.cpp

which is outside the project directory.

If in cmake I use the abs path (given as a parameter to add_executable):

/prj/confstruct/src/debug/mpir.cpp

then resharper ignores the file.
If I add the drive letter:

c:/prj/confstruct/src/debug/mpir.cpp

Then resharper works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file is used somewhere in your project, i.e. is included into one of your .cpp files. Turn on the "Enable inspections, quick fixes and context actions in files external to the solution" option in ReSharper settings: [image: option]

Comment: added details   -------------

Comment: If you can, send a repro solution to JetBrains support.

Comment: I solved it, see edit.

Comment: If possible, please create a repro solution and send it to JetBrains support for investigation.

Comment: To reproduce the problem: create any makefile, e.g. https://riptutorial.com/cmake/example/7501/simple--hello-world--project. Provide an absolute path to one of the source files. Giving you something specific that contains a path on my computer won't help you.

If you think about it, the bug is kind of expected. Resharper expects relative paths, and if it gets an absolute one, it appends it to the current path and fails.

Comment: Ok thanks, filed https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-33152/